# Prove or disapprove that integral converges

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin(x+\frac{1}{x})|}{\sqrt{x}}$. I think that this integral doesn't converge, but I can't prove it. Can you help me, please?

I can prove it with the help of change $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$, but maybe there is a much more easier way without such computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin\theta\gt1/2$ when $\pi/3+2\pi k\le\theta\le2\pi/3+2\pi k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Consequently, for large $k$, we have

$$\int_{\pi/3+2\pi k}^{\pi/2+2\pi k}{|\sin(x+1/x)|\over\sqrt x}dx\gt{1\over2}\int_{\pi/3+2\pi k}^{\pi/2+2\pi k}{1\over\sqrt x}dx\gt{1\over2}\cdot{\pi/2-\pi/3\over\sqrt{\pi/2+2\pi k}}\gt{1\over1{,}000{,}000\sqrt k}$$

where the final inequality is intentionally crude, to emphasize the point that all that really matters is the square root of $k$; the subtle point is that using $\pi/2$ in the upper limit allows us to say that $x\le\pi/2+2\pi k$ implies $x+1/x\le2\pi/3+2\pi k$ (for which we need $k$ to be "large").

We now have

$$\int_1^\infty{|\sin(x+1/x)|\over\sqrt x}dx\gt\sum_k\int_{\pi/3+2\pi k}^{\pi/2+2\pi k}{|\sin(x+1/x)|\over\sqrt x}dx\gt{1\over1{,}000{,}000}\sum_k{1\over\sqrt k}=\infty$$